# glsl - get pixel color [pixel shader]

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Is there any way to get drawed pixel color (from backbuffer, not current drawing pixel)?

For example:
I'm drawing a rectangle with texture and then drawing a circle (in blue color) on this rectangle. If I use pixel shader on a circle, is there any way to get current pixel color from backbuffer (pixel from rectangle)?

Comment: Draw into an FBO and then composite the two together. But generally there is no other way to do this, some Android and iOS devices have an [OpenGL ES extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/EXT/EXT_shader_framebuffer_fetch.txt) that allows you to read the framebuffer directly without this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to get the color of the pixel from the frame buffer for that use glReadPixels() which will return the pixel data from the frame buffer.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml

Comment: That won't help here, he wants to read the framebuffer from the pixel (fragment) shader.

Comment: @CodeStepper: It sort of is, especially if you are using a certain GPU model in iOS or Android ( the extension that allows that doesn't exist in desktop OpenGL :-\ ), but usually what you end up having to do is draw in multiple passes using different Framebuffer Object attachments. You could read back the pixels drawn from your rectangle using a texture lookup if you did that.